# Integrate $\frac{1}{x\,\log{x}}$ by parts

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

A naive indefinite integration of the function $\dfrac{1}{x\,\log{x}}$ can be performed as follows:

Let

$
\begin{eqnarray}
I  &=& \int\dfrac{dx}{x\,\log{x}}\\
\therefore I &=& \dfrac{1}{\log{x}}\int\dfrac{dx}{x} - \int\left\{\dfrac{d}{dx} \left(\dfrac{1}{\log{x}}\right) \int \dfrac{dx}{x} \right\}dx\\
&=& \dfrac{1}{\log{x}} \cdot \log{x}-\int - \dfrac{1}{(\log{x})^2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{x}\cdot\log{x}\,dx\\
&=& 1 + \int\dfrac{dx}{x\,\log{x}}\\
&=& 1+I
\end{eqnarray}
$

This obviously leads to something like $1=0$. Can anyone please tell me what is going wrong? Thanks in advance.

PS. I know that the corrct answer would be $\log(\log{x})$.

Comment: Are you forced to use Integration By Parts?

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to [make it take up less vertical space](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/290189) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\int \frac{dx}{x\log(x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335709/int-fracdxx-logx) (this question is about exactly the same issue)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your conclusion is not correct.

It only says that the two **indefinite** integrals can differ by $1$, which is a special case of the fact that antiderivatives of the same function can differ by a constant.

Answer (score 2):

If you replace the undefinite integrals by definite ones, you end up with

$$I=0+I,$$
which is harmless. The devil is the integration constant.

You may rescue the reasoning by writing

$$I=\frac{\log x}{\log x}+C+I$$ and you conclude that $C=-1$ (and there remains another integration constant in $I$).